# How do I detect iBeacon device without knowind uuid in iOS?

Tags: swift, ibeacon

I would like to develop app which detects a lot of beacon device withoud knowing uuid.
However I cannot find way to do this in internet.
I have to define uuid in code.

So is there way to detect iBeacon without knowing uuid?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20988671/how-to-scan-ibeacon-signals-without-specifying-uuid

Answer (score 0):

I know CoreLocation requires you to know the UUID of the beacon you are [CBCentralManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCentralManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CBCentralManager), which handles all of the bluetooth spectrum.  It has methods for scanning for bluetooth devices.  I don't have an iBeacon handy at the moment to test and see if it picks them up, but it is probably worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

The nomenclature used is quite important here. If you want to detect 'iBeacon', then you need to at least know the UUID of the device or devices you're looking for. That's because, in the iBeacon standard, the ID is the only piece of information included in the advertising packet. iBeacon lets you do two things: monitoring and ranging (detecting whether there is an iBeacon in range, and detecting how close the iBeacon is), and both require you to know the UUID.

If you just want to look for beacons, without including the iBeacon properties and features, you can use Core Bluetooth to do that. SDKs of particular beacon vendors base their beacon maintenance features (firmware updates, settings changing) on that. This method is also used by vendors that use their own protocols alongside Apple's iBeacon. We do that at Estimote with Estimote Stickers, and AFAIK Gimbal does this as well.

Cheers.